# Virtual, Override and new keys in inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the following code:

```
   class Animal
    {
        public virtual void Invoke()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Animal");
        }
    }
    class Dog : Animal
    {
        public override void Invoke()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dog");
        }
    }
    class Dobberman : Dog
    {
        public new void Invoke()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dobberman");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Animal dog = new Dobberman();
            dog.Invoke();
            Dobberman dog2 = new Dobberman();
            dog2.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

Why would it print "Dog" in the first output? and why "Dobberman" in the second? What is going on under the hood?

Comment: https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/liskov-substitution-principle/

Answer (score -1):

`Invoke` is virtual on `Animal`, is overridden by `Dog`, and *hidden* by `Dobberman` (SIC)

Remember that methods are bound at *compile* time, then looks for overrides at *runtime* for virtual methods.

So the binding is as follows:

```
Animal dog = new Dobberman(); 
// binds to Dog.Invoke since the variable type is Animal, 
// the runtime type is Dog
// and Dog overrides Animal.Invoke
dog.Invoke();  

Dobberman dog2 = new Dobberman();
// binds to Dobberman.Invoke since the variable type is Dobberman
dog2.Invoke();
```